# JQuery ToolTip Help for Multiple Items

Tags: javascript, jquery, tooltip

I'm a beginner and just learning, so I was hoping to get some quick help with some code that I'm using to help me with a project I'm working on.

Basically, the code that I'm using to help me with my project is shown below, and it's only letting me show one tool tip for each element.  How would I be able to have each element show a different tooltip using this code?  Your help is much appreciated!

```
    <html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
    #hint{
        cursor:pointer;
    }
    .tooltip{
        margin:8px;
        padding:8px;
        border:1px solid blue;
        background-color:yellow;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 2;
    }
</style>

</head>

<body>

<h1>jQuery tooltips example</h1>

<label id="username">Username : </label><input type="text" / size="50"> 
<span id="hint">hint (mouseover me)</span>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

    var changeTooltipPosition = function(event) {
      var tooltipX = event.pageX - 8;
      var tooltipY = event.pageY + 8;
      $('div.tooltip').css({top: tooltipY, left: tooltipX});
    };

    var showTooltip = function(event) {
      $('div.tooltip').remove();
      $('<div class="tooltip">I\' am tooltips! tooltips! tooltips! :)</div>')
            .appendTo('body');
      changeTooltipPosition(event);
    };

    var hideTooltip = function() {
       $('div.tooltip').remove();
    };

    $("span#hint,label#username'").bind({
       mousemove : changeTooltipPosition,
       mouseenter : showTooltip,
       mouseleave: hideTooltip
    });
});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is a link to [test](http://jsfiddle.net/BXT8L/1/).

Comment: Can't seem to get your fiddle to work correctly, even after selecting a version of jQuery to use with it.

Comment: Also, what's the use case for why you need to use jQuery for tooltips? Are they going to change all the time?

Answer (score 0):

Try something more like this?

```
var changeTooltipPosition = function(event) {
      var tooltipX = event.pageX - 8;
      var tooltipY = event.pageY + 8;
      $('div.tooltip').css({top: tooltipY, left: tooltipX});
    };

var showTooltip = function(event) {
    console.log($(event.target).data('tip'));
    var tip = $(event.target).data('tip');
    $('div.tooltip').remove();
    $('<div>', {
        class: "tooltip",
        html: "I am "+tip+" :)"
    })
    .appendTo('body');
    changeTooltipPosition(event);
};

var hideTooltip = function() {
    $('div.tooltip').remove();
};

$("#username, #hint").hover(
    function(e){
        showTooltip(e);
    },
    function(e){
        hideTooltip(e);
    }
);
```

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/2kzeX/1/